# Two div's next to each other but first div going to second line

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario where I have two divs.  I would like the second div to immediately follow the first.  Currently, the space I have to work with is small, so the text in the first div is too large for one line and it wraps to a second line.  Event hough this occurs, I would like that second div to come directly after the first (and in this case after the end of the first div on the second line.

```
<div id="one" style="display: inline-block;">
  <div id="two" style="float: left;"></div>
  <div id="three" style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

This works fine when the text is div with the id of two is small but when it is large it wraps to a second line and the div with the id of three goes below div two.

Comment: you have some typos (missing `"`)

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle (which will help resolve the typos)

Comment: float rules must be accompanied with a `width` declaration. If no width is defined, #two and #three will be 100% wide, so they won't be able to line up next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
<div id="two" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="three style="float: left;"></div>
```

To

```
<div id="two" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

NOTE: You no need to float both the div to left

Comment: Show us some fiddle which will help us to break your problem further