# how to place two div's next to each other, when first div is in two lines?

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement to place two div next to each other (second div starts where first end). I found relevant question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409257/two-divs-next-to-each-other-but-first-div-going-to-second-line) but not the answer.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">The two divs are,when first line goes to second then, second div is not appearing </div>
    <div id="div2">next to each other.</div>
</div>
#div1 {
   float:left;
    display: inline-block;

}
#div2 {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rajcse123/nrzey328/) example that i tried...

The requirement is, if first div ends in second line first word then second div should start with second word of second line.

Comment: See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nrzey328/1/), your code is working fine

Comment: give some width to your div, so that they know where their limit ends, and add `;` to `#div1 {float:left}` or simply remove `float:left` from both the div, 2nd text would start where 1st text ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add to both div in css-

```
width: 50%;
```

**UPDATE**

Also missing semicolon at the end of `float:left;` of `#div1`. Add semicolon there.

Comment: updated [fiddeler](http://jsfiddle.net/rajcse123/nrzey328/2/) I want result The two divs are,when first line goes to second then, second div is not appearing next to each other. not The two divs are,when first line goes to second then, second div is not appearing \n
next to each other.

Comment: as just mentioned above in my UPDATE, add the missing 'semicolon'...it should help.

Comment: it is appear next to each other, but what i need is second div should start immediately where first div ends. Means second div should start in second line ending point of first div data

Comment: then you don't need to add `width: 50%;` in any of your div. Only adding semicolon should help the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `display: inline-block;` on both of the *div* elements and they will appear next to each other. In your fiddle you have a missing semicolon after the first `float: left`, which breaks the rest of your stylesheet. By omitting the `float: left` property on both *div*s, there will be a space between them. Here's two examples, one without `float: left` and one with:

### Without `float: left`

```css
#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1">The two divs are,when first line goes to second then, second div is not appearing</div>
  <div id="div2">next to each other.</div>
</div>
```

### With `float: left`

```css
#div1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#div2 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1">The two divs are,when first line goes to second then, second div is not appearing</div>
  <div id="div2">next to each other.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of div try using span see if it works for you..

```html
<span>some text some text some text some text some textsome text some text some text vsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text</span>
<span>next line text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need inline-block?
Added background colors to show the `div` boxes

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
        The two divs are,when first line goes to second then, second div is not appearing
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        next to each other.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
    float:left;
    //display: inline-block;
    background: red;
}
#div2 {
    float:left;
    //display: inline-block;
    background: blue
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrzey328/3/